# How can I retrieve the docstring for a property of a Python class instance?

Tags: python, properties, docstring

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class TestCase(object):
    """Class docstring"""

    def meth(self):
        """Method docstring"""
        return 1

    @property
    def prop(self):
        """Property docstring"""
        return 2
```

It's easy enough for me to get the docstrings for the class itself, or for a regular method:

```
tc = TestCase()

print(tc.__doc__)
# Class docstring

print(tc.meth.__doc__)
# Method docstring
```

However, this approach doesn't work for properties - instead I get the `__doc__` attribute of whatever object is returned by the property getter method (in this case, `int`):

```
print(tc.prop.__doc__)
# int(x=0) -> int or long
# int(x, base=10) -> int or long
# ...
```

The same thing applies to `getattr(tc, "prop").__doc__` and `getattr(tc.prop, "__doc__")`.

I know that Python's introspection mechanisms are capable of accessing the docstring I'm looking for. For example, when I call `help(tc)` I get:

```
class TestCase(__builtin__.object)
 |  Class docstring
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  meth(self)
 |      Method docstring
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  prop
 |      Property docstring
```

How is `help` able to access the docstring for `tc.prop`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are trying to access the `__doc__` from the instance which will try to first , evaluate the property, for which the returned value may have no attribute `__doc__`, or use the `__doc__` of the returned type.

Instead, you should access the `__doc__` for the `property` from the class itself:

```
TestCase.prop.__doc__
```

So to extend this to your class instance, you would use `__class__` to get the class of the instance and then the property, and finally the `__doc__`:

```
tc.__class__.prop.__doc__
```

Or use `type` to fetch the class:

```
type(tc).prop.__doc__
```

Comment: Given an instance of `TestCase` I would need to use `tc.__class__.prop.__doc__` or `type(tc).prop.__doc__`, but you're right.